# how to replace special character in linux variables

Tags: shell, awk, sed

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Please Enter you OS Password:" PASSWORD
echo "the password is $PASSWORD"
```

input: `Test$1234`

We want the output as `Test\$1234`

Comment: Not clear, please wrap your code up into code tags and then write down all conditions which we need or our are using with your effort to solve it.

Comment: @chinta, I have provided you a solution.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem: **why** do you want to escape the non-word character?  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf "%q" $PASSWORD` to "shell-escape" the contents of `$PASSWORD`. This does not only take care of `$`, but also other special shell characters, such as `!`, `&`, `>`, etc.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Please Enter you OS Password:" PASSWORD
PASSWORD=$(printf "%q" $PASSWORD)
echo "the password is $PASSWORD"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below command, here `sed` command will replace `$` with `\$` and will not replace any other special character so no side effect:-

```
!/bin/bash

read -p "Please Enter you OS Password:" PASSWORD 
PASSWORD=$(echo $PASSWORD |sed 's/\$/\\$/g')
echo "the password is $PASSWORD"
```

Comment: More generally, you can write `sed 's/[^[:alnum:]_]/\\&/g'` to escape *any* non-word character.